# fast R lookup table

Tags: r

Similar questions were asked before, but without clear generic answers.  (And Joseph Adler's experiments are no longer on the web, and his book just says "write an S4 class.")

Assume a large lookup table with multiple indexes.  Assume a modest size set of values to look up.  Even an R merge is very slow.  Here is an example:

```
{
    L <- 100000000  ## only 100M entries for 1GB*4 of int data
    lookuptable  <- data.frame( i1=sample(1:L), i2=sample(1:L), v1=rnorm(L), v2=rnorm(L) )
    NLUP <- 10      ## look up only 10+1 values in large table
    vali <- sample(1:L, NLUP)
    lookmeup <- data.frame( i1= c(lookuptable[vali,1], -1),
                       i2= c(lookuptable[vali,2],-1), vA=rnorm(11) )
    rm(vali); rm(L)
}

## I want to speed this up---how?
system.time( merge( lookmeup, lookuptable,  by.x=c("i1","i3"), by.y=c("i1","i2"),
                   all.x=T, all.y=F, sort=F ) )
```

(Try it!  500 second on my 2019 iMac).  So what is the recommended way of doing this?

I could write code that creates unique integer fingerprints from the columns first (for fast comparisons), and then I just match on one column.  But this is not easy either, 'cause I need to avoid accidental duplicate fingerprints, or add more logic for conflicts.

Given integer fingerprints, I could then use either `data.table` with `setkey` on the fingerprints (or can it encapsulate two-column indexes, too?  I tried but failed, perhaps because I am not a regular user); or I could write a C program that takes two integer fingerprint columns and returns one.

Comment: I suspect `data.table` with `setkey` will be pretty fast here (and should be able to handle two-column matches without creating "fingerprints"), but it might depend on whether you're just doing this once or multiple times, as it takes time to sort the table with `setkey`.

Comment: Given that this should be generic and lookuptable can itself contain many entries (here just 10), it presumably makes sense to sort.  do you have an example with `setkey` on arbitrary number of columns that can encapsulate the lookup?

Comment: Using `L <- 1E7` (1/10th your size), dplyr's left_join was about 5x faster for that operation, FWIW.   `system.time( dplyr::left_join( lookmeup, lookuptable, by = c("i1" = "i1", "i3" = "i2")))`

Comment: as per Marius comment, you can try `library(data.table); setDT(lookuptable, key=c("i1","i2")); setDT(lookmeup, key=c("i1","i2"))[lookuptable, c("v1", "v2") := .(v1, v2)]`

Comment: this may be the best that R can currently do (perhaps given the required generality), but there is still a lot of room for improvement.  I experimented with a similar C program with similar dimensions.  The sort takes less than 5 seconds, the ladder-merge-lookup takes about 1 second (which is the most time-intensive part of the R code).  Add the remerge, and a better R programmer could probably write a version that can do this in <20 seconds, rather than 100 or 500.

Comment: chinsoon12---can you post a version as an answer (perhaps with simple timing) that is a little more general, imitating the merge for arbitrary keys and values, encapsulated as a `merge.lookup( needles, heystack, by.x, by.y ) -> data.frame` , please?  this would be one good answer.

Comment: yes, it would.  I would be happy to accept it...which is why I suggested you do this.  best, /iaw

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally broke down and made this a more generic function:

```
set.seed(0); K <- 1000; M <- K*K
rint <- function( n, minv=0, maxv=NA ) sample( minv:(if (is.na(maxv)) n else maxv), n, repl=T )


dict.lookup <- function( dwords, dictionary, by=NULL, by.w=NULL, by.d=NULL ) {
                                        # bad style, but just (mostly symmetric) error checking
    if (is.null(by.d)) by.d <- by; if (is.null(by.w)) by.w <- by
    stopifnot( (!is.null(by.d)) & (!is.null(by.w)))
                                        # valid input checking
    stopifnot( is.data.frame( dwords ) ); stopifnot( is.data.frame( dictionary ) )
    stopifnot( nrow( dwords ) > 0 ); stopifnot( nrow( dictionary ) > 0 )
    stopifnot( is.character(by.w) ); stopifnot( is.character(by.d) )
    stopifnot( length(by.w)==1 ); stopifnot( length(by.d)==1)
    stopifnot( by.w %in% names(dwords) ); stopifnot( by.d %in% names(dictionary) )
                                        # you cannot give the words directly.  hash them first
    stopifnot( is.numeric( dwords[[by.w]] ) )
    stopifnot( is.numeric( dictionary[[by.d]] ) )
                                        # a dictionary should have only unique entries
    stopifnot( anyDuplicated( dictionary[[by.d]] ) == 0 )

                                        # the actual work
    toright <- dictionary[ match(dwords[[by.w]], dictionary[[by.d]]), ]
    cbind(dwords, toright[ , names(toright) != by.d ])
}


L <- 100*M  ## only 100M entries for 1GB*4 of int data
dictionary  <- data.frame( idictwords=sample(1:L), cost2print=rint(L, 1,100),  tiresomeness=rint(L, 100,200) )
message("created dictionary")

## look up 10+1 words
dwords <- data.frame( imywords= c(dictionary[ sample(1:L, 10) , "idictwords"], -99),  frombook=rint(11, 200,300) )
message("created my words")

print( system.time( o <- dict.lookup( dwords, dictionary, by.w= "imywords", by.d= "idictwords" ) ) )
message("looked up my words in dictionary done")

print(o)
```

gives me

```
   user  system elapsed 
 13.746   0.739  14.489 

         imywords frombook cost2print tiresomeness
68533657 88509161      263         25          110
87030862 75614422      297         23          164
16923080 79185053      249         84          105
62235248 84542527      292         72          141
4044547  35212219      201         13          155
95995528 67895828      257          4          122
43031831 24227004      281         86          101
76602707 55164521      270         52          151
53380001 87665273      207         35          121
24278223 30085231      238          6          153
NA            -99      205         NA           NA
```

the rownames are the matching rows from the dictionary data frame.

I often tinker with functions (often to get better handling).  feel free to suggest changes.

Comment: What does this do that `data.table` doesn't do much faster already?

Answer (score 6):

To [match two `data.frames` on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26596305/10488504) you can use from *base* [merge](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) or [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) in combination with [interaction](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/interaction.html), [paste](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) or use a [list](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html). It is also possible to [map two integers to one, in a unique and deterministic way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919612/10488504). A simple extension is the `fastmatch` library which can be faster than `match` from *base*. Also `dplyr` or `data.table` can be an option. Have also a look at: [Matching more than 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18319985/10488504), [How to join (merge) data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/10488504) and [Fast single item lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34232865/10488504).

```
library(fastmatch)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(times = 10L, setup = gc(), check = "equivalent"
 , merge = merge(lookMeUp, lookupTable, all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
 , dplyr = left_join(lookMeUp, lookupTable, by = c("i1", "i2"))
 , inter = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[match(interaction(lookMeUp[c("i1","i2")])
                 , interaction(lookupTable[c("i1","i2")])), 3:4])
 , paste = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[match(paste(lookMeUp$i1, lookMeUp$i2)
                 , paste(lookupTable$i1, lookupTable$i2)), 3:4])
 , int = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[match(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * max(lookupTable$i1)
                 , lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * max(lookupTable$i1)), 3:4])
 , fInter = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(interaction(lookMeUp[c("i1","i2")])
                 , interaction(lookupTable[c("i1","i2")])), 3:4])
 , fPaste = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(paste(lookMeUp$i1, lookMeUp$i2)
                  , paste(lookupTable$i1, lookupTable$i2)), 3:4])
 , fint = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * max(lookMeUp$i1)
                 , lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * max(lookMeUp$i1)), 3:4])
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  merge 2547.72575 2564.72138 2590.03400 2578.14307 2585.01870 2735.23435    10
#  dplyr  690.55046  695.56161  703.01335  703.95085  707.32141  714.00890    10
#  inter  511.86378  514.36418  528.73905  529.14331  535.33359  552.20183    10
#  paste  750.01340  763.84494  942.47309  777.73232 1273.83380 1377.00192    10
#    int   71.56913   72.15233   73.27748   72.92613   73.89630   77.01510    10
# fInter  447.82012  450.00472  459.51196  455.82473  464.85767  491.52366    10
# fPaste  713.68824  719.60794  796.94680  726.70971  788.36997 1316.64071    10
#   fint   59.04541   59.13039   60.95638   60.59758   62.58539   63.65308    10
```

Instead of creating the unique identifier each time you make a look up, you can store it in the lookup table, what will make the lookup faster but you have an overhead in creating it. You can also sort the lookup table by this identifier which will allow accessing the data line without using `match` but this method will add not defined rows in case there are some combinations missing, what will be equivalent in creation a `matrix` or `array`. You can also use the *build in hash* for looking up variables in an `environment`. Also the *binary search* from `findInterval` can be used.

```
system.time({maxLTi1 <- max(lookupTable$i1); lookupTable$id <- lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * maxLTi1})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.006       0.000       0.006 

system.time(fmatch(c(lookupTable$id[1], 0), lookupTable$id))  #Create Hash
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.056       0.000       0.056 
#system.time(fmatch(lookupTable$id[1], lookupTable$id))  #Create Hash in case you have only matches
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.016       0.004       0.020 

system.time({
lookupTableS <- lookupTable[0,]
lookupTableS[lookupTable$id,] <- lookupTable #Sort Table with gaps
})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.080       0.011       0.091 

system.time({
lookupTableS2 <- lookupTable[order(lookupTable$id),] #Sort Table
})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.074       0.000       0.074 

library(Matrix)
system.time({ #Sorted Sparse Vector
  i <- order(lookupTable$id)
  lookupTableS3 <- sparseVector(i, lookupTable$id[i], max(lookupTable$id))})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.057       0.008       0.065 

system.time(lupEnv <- list2env(setNames(as.list(seq_len(nrow(lookupTable))), paste(lookupTable$i1, lookupTable$i2))))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      4.824       0.056       4.880 

library(data.table);
lookupTableDT <- as.data.table(copy(lookupTable))
lookMeUpDT <- as.data.table(copy(lookMeUp))
system.time(setkey(lookupTableDT, i1, i2))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.094       0.000       0.027 

lookMeUpDT$id <- lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * max(lookupTable$i1)
lookupTableDTId <- as.data.table(copy(lookupTable))
system.time(setkey(lookupTableDTId, id))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.091       0.000       0.026 

lookMeUpDTId <- copy(lookMeUpDT)
lookMeUpDTId$row <- seq_len(nrow(lookMeUpDTId))
setkey(lookMeUpDTId, id)

microbenchmark(times = 10L, setup = gc(), check = "equivalent"
 , int = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[match(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * max(lookupTable$i1)
                 , lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * max(lookupTable$i1)), 3:4])
 , fint = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * max(lookMeUp$i1)
                 , lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * max(lookMeUp$i1)), 3:4])
 , id = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[match(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1
                 , lookupTable$id), 3:4])
 , sparid = {i <- lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1
   j <- i
   j[i>0] <- as.vector(lookupTableS3[i[i>0]])
   cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[ifelse(j>0,j,NA), 3:4])}
 , DT = merge(lookMeUpDT[,1:3], lookupTableDT[,1:4], by=c("i1", "i2"), all.x=TRUE, sort = FALSE)
 , DTid = merge(lookMeUpDT, lookupTableDTId[,-2:-1], by=c("id"), all.x=TRUE, sort = FALSE)[,-1]
 , DiIdKey = merge(lookMeUpDTId, lookupTableDTId[,-2:-1], all.x=TRUE, sort = FALSE)[order(row),][,c(-1,-5)]
 , findInt = {i <- lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1
    j  <- findInterval(i, lookupTableS2$id)
    j[j==0]  <- NA
    j[i != lookupTableS2$id[j]] <- NA
    cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTableS2[j, 3:4])}
 , envir = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[vapply(paste(lookMeUp$i1, lookMeUp$i2), function(i) {x  <- lupEnv[[i]]; if(is.null(x)) NA else x}, 1), 3:4])
 , fid = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1
                 , lookupTable$id), 3:4])
 , sid = cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTableS[ifelse(lookMeUp$i1 > 0, lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1, NA), 3:4])
)
#Unit: microseconds
#    expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#     int 75167.977 76446.819 77817.3349 77958.9650 78649.235 80656.715    10
#    fint 63332.436 63948.769 64574.8881 64194.2765 64942.559 66808.193    10
#      id 68198.639 69293.551 70477.6062 70223.0505 71393.354 74951.007    10
#  sparid  9181.928  9217.312  9552.0241  9478.8475  9561.917 10895.649    10
#      DT  4990.075  5000.857  5125.6716  5051.4970  5157.057  5547.220    10
#    DTid  4167.229  4189.703  4250.0804  4232.8955  4289.718  4440.924    10
# DiIdKey  4547.589  4582.915  4626.9514  4597.6790  4634.311  4867.630    10
# findInt  2795.560  2813.100  2854.7069  2815.4890  2857.084  3097.120    10
#   envir   526.971   530.459   537.5767   532.9755   546.402   551.231    10
#     fid   424.790   425.218   433.7295   433.3335   441.673   444.026    10
#     sid   436.135   439.688   445.1770   441.5705   445.331   464.685    10

#In case order and columns need not be like the others
microbenchmark(times = 10L, setup = gc(), unit = "us",
 DiIdKey = merge(lookMeUpDTId, lookupTableDTId, all.x=TRUE, sort = FALSE))
#Unit: microseconds
#    expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
# DiIdKey 1692.629 1706.14 1719.556 1717.142 1722.067 1778.88    10
```

Creating a *unique identifier* and store it in the lookup table and using *`fmatch`* could be **recommended**. In pure *base* the lookup table could be sorted by the ID and missing combinations will be filled with NA what allows direct access to the matching rows without using `match`. Alternatively the lookup can be done in an environment where the build in hash search is used but this has much overhead. Also using `findInterval` shows good results.

In case the columns are not (positive) `integer` cast them to `factor` and use their integer values.

Data:

```
set.seed(7)
sqrtN  <- 1e3
lookupTable <- data.frame(expand.grid(i1=seq_len(sqrtN), i2=seq_len(sqrtN)), v1=seq_len(sqrtN*sqrtN))[sample(sqrtN*sqrtN),]
lookupTable$v2  <- seq_len(sqrtN*sqrtN)

lookMeUp <- rbind(lookupTable[sample(nrow(lookupTable), 10), 1:2], c(-1, -1))
lookMeUp$vA <- letters[1:nrow(lookMeUp)]
```

Timings of lookuptable with 5e7 rows:

```
sqrtN  <- 7.1e3
lookupTable <- data.frame(expand.grid(i1=seq_len(sqrtN), i2=seq_len(sqrtN)), v1=seq_len(sqrtN*sqrtN))[sample(sqrtN*sqrtN),]
lookupTable$v2  <- seq_len(sqrtN*sqrtN)

lookMeUp <- rbind(lookupTable[sample(nrow(lookupTable), 10), 1:2], c(-1, -1))
lookMeUp$vA <- letters[1:nrow(lookMeUp)]

system.time({maxLTi1 <- max(lookupTable$i1); lookupTable$id <- lookupTable$i1 + lookupTable$i2 * maxLTi1})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.312       0.016       0.329 

system.time(lookupTable <- lookupTable[order(lookupTable$id),]) #For findIntervall
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      6.786       0.120       6.905 

system.time({
i <- lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1
j  <- findInterval(i, lookupTable$id)
j[j==0]  <- NA
j[i != lookupTable$id[j]] <- NA
cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[j, 3:4])
})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.099       0.048       0.147 

system.time(fmatch(c(lookupTable$id[1], 0), lookupTable$id)) #Create Hash
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      2.642       0.120       2.762 

system.time(cbind(lookMeUp, lookupTable[fmatch(lookMeUp$i1 + lookMeUp$i2 * maxLTi1, lookupTable$id), 3:4]))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#          0           0           0
```

Comment: great, but an even better answer would roll this all into a function that is a drop-in replacement for merge...heck, this should be part of the R base!