# R: lapply with data.table slow, is there a faster alternative?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I got a table in which I would like to replace values of a single column using a lookup-table.

Using lapply this works fine.
However, with a huge dataset it runs hours.

Is there a faster alternative?
Thanks!

MWE:

```
require(data.table)

# Dummy data. 
dt_lookup <- data.table(cls_old=c(1:5), cls_new=c(5:1)) # Lookup-Table, the real data has different and non-continous entries.
dt <- data.table(cls=c(5:1), data=c(1,2,3,4,5)) # Table in which data shall be replaced depending on the lookup-table.

# Function to get the new column entry for every row based on the lookup-table.
get_new_label <- function(cls) {
  return(dt_lookup[cls_old==cls]$cls_new)
}

# Actual replacement of values.
dt <- dt[,cls:=lapply(cls, get_new_label)]
```

Comment: I think this is commonly referred to as "_update join_", so use that in your search (together with R and data.table) and ye shall find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding something, you can do a simple join:

```
dt[dt_lookup, cls := i.cls_new, on = .(cls = cls_old)]
dt
#   cls data
#1:   1    1
#2:   2    2
#3:   3    3
#4:   4    4
#5:   5    5
```

You should really spend some time and study the data.table vignettes and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to realize a *lookup-table*.

```
i <- match(dt$cls, dt_lookup$cls_old)
j <- !is.na(i)
dt$cls[j] <- dt_lookup$cls_new[i[j]]
dt
#   cls data
#1:   1    1
#2:   2    2
#3:   3    3
#4:   4    4
#5:   5    5
```

Also have a look at [fast R lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59673734/10488504).